# Making a WPF application retain focus at all times

Tags: wpf, focus

I've got an issue with a WPF application that I'm writing. The app needs to be able to keep focus at all times. The computer it's running on is a highly specialized machine with the only purpose of running this application.

There is no keyboard connected to the machine (it has a touch screen), so the only thing that can steal focus is windows own "needy windows", such as windows update etc.

How can I make it so that my app retains focus at all times? Is it possible to make the entire app modal?

## EDIT:

Thank you both for your answers. I think I'll end up using Topsmost for now, but I'll definitely check out the source of babysmash as that application works exactly the way I want mine to, in regards to the way it handles focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the source of [BabySmash](http://www.codeplex.com/babysmash). It is specifically designed to keep focus even under quite bizar circumstances. (It is a program designed to run at full screen and let babys smash on a keyboard - so quite some focus went into capturing all kinds of weird keyboard combinations and alert messages).

Comment: This still best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
<Window ... Topmost="True">
```

i xaml. But maybe this is not what you are looking for